# android - showing listView in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, preferenceactivity, baseadapter

i wish to show a listView on a PreferenceActivity similar to what the android OS wifi-settings has for the list of networks (example [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/56742088@N06/5395382392/) , on the bottom area of the image) .
however , such a thing isn't availabe ,  so i've created a new class that extends Preference , and what i returned in the onCreateView is just a ListView instance .

it worked , but the listView has a constant size of about a single item no matter what i do to its layoutParams and no matter what i do to the adapter . even if i set the adapter inside the onCreateView , it has the exact same size .

not only that , but the listView cannot be scrolled , even though it is clear that it has multiple items within it .

i would , of course, want to use the same text size standard as on all of the preferences , to give a native feeling.

can anyone please tell me what can be done in order to make it work well?

btw, the app should work for android API 10+ (minimum 10) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , the answer would be to use setContentView to whatever layout you wish (including any views you wish) , add there a listView for the preferences , and for this listView , call bind and setAdapter.

i've found this solution by looking at other solutions, like this one:
http://kmansoft.com/2011/08/29/implementing-long-clickable-preferences/

Answer (score 2):

In case you are going for the same appearance / behavior, you should stay with the plain `PreferenceActivity` implementation, and add the new `preference items` into the "list" dynamically from code (eventually with custom renderers).

A basic implementation of such display would be:

```
/**
 * This variable stands for the items with which you want to populate the list
 */
final HashMap<String, String> networks = new HashMap<String, String>();

final PreferenceCategory cat = new PreferenceCategory(getApplicationContext());
cat.setTitle(R.string.wifinetworks); // holding "Wi-fi networks"
for (final String networkTitle : networks.keySet())
{
    final Preference pref = new Preference(getApplicationContext());
    pref.setTitle(networkTitle);
    pref.setSummary(networks.get(networkTitle));
    cat.addPreference(pref);
}
```

**Edit**: For adding custom components to an existing `PreferenceActivity`, you should give a try to the `addContentView` method. From within `onCreate`:

```
final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
addContentView(buttonBar, params);
```

Comment: so you mean i should not use a listView at all , and instead simply add&remove items even on runtime? what about the scrolling feature? it seems that when i add a scrollView , the size of the "list" shrinks and stay to the same size... the scrolling also doesn't work

Comment: the `PreferenceActivity`'s screen does have already the scrolling feature, so you don't need to add an other one.

Comment: is it possible perhaps to use the default styles as on the preferenceActivity , inside a normal activity ? i need to have native feeling , but some things are just not there . for example , if i need to have buttons on the bottom side , beneath the listView , i can't use it here since you say that all items should be in the same list, and pressing them would require full scrolling down the list.

Comment: please see my update. `PreferenceActivity` is still an activity with a base layout, and with the `addContentView` method you can add more items to it. Or you can access it's list, and change it's layout parameters from `getListView().setLayoutParams(...);`

Comment: that's a nice idea for a workaround, but the inserted view is set to be on top of the current views . so , if i choose to insert a listView this way , and there are preferences (for example a CheckBoxPreference ) , it will be on top of them . maybe the layout is FrameLayout .